# Transition ImageView Animation

Tags: android, animation, imageview, android-transitions

I wanna make my imageView animated as it enters from Activity A to Activity B  via onClickListener and set itself into another imageView. These are my Activities.

Activity A:

[image: Activity A image description here]

Activity B:

[image]

I want to to be animated something like this: [Animation](https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0B08MbvYZK1iNT2dLWHE1NG8tV00/animation-meaningfultransitions-consistentchoreography-do1_large_xhdpi.webm)

I dont know where to start and how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use SharedTransitions. [Here](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2015/01/activity-fragment-shared-element-transitions-in-depth-part3a.html) is a very good article on how these transitions work and how to implement them.